# Can't figure out how to 'assert' properly for psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently creating some tests for a model I created. The test is checking to see if the `first_name` NOT NULL constraint is working for that field.

It should do that by checking if the `object.save()` method fails. If it fails then the assertation should return pass.

My test method looks like this:

```
def test_tutor_fname_notnull(self):
    '''
    Test passes if first_name NOT NULL constraint is working. If first_name is missing, data should not be saved to DB and return false.
    '''
    stevie = Tutors(last_name='wonder',email='sboywonder@gmail.com',birth_day='1990-01-02') 
    self.assertIs(stevie.save(), False)
```

The assertation fails and returns this:

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "first_name" of relation "artsubjects_tutors" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, wonder, sboywonder@gmail.com, 1990-01-02).
```

This means the NOT NULL constraint is working and that the assertation should pass. But the assertation actually fails.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any idea on how I could better handle this assertation as to make it pass as intended when the `object.save()` method fails as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You should assert that it raises an error, with [**`.assertRaises(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
from psycopg2.errors import NotNullViolation

# …

def test_tutor_fname_notnull(self):
    '''
    Test passes if first_name NOT NULL constraint is working. If first_name is missing, data should not be saved to DB and return false.
    '''
    stevie = Tutors(last_name='wonder',email='sboywonder@gmail.com',birth_day='1990-01-02') 
    with self.assertRaises(NotNullViolation):
        stevie.save()
```

By using this as a context manager (with the `with` keyword), the test will catch the `NotNullViolation`, and will let the test fail if no such exception is raised.

Comment: Im going to read that doc, thanks Willem! New to testing things, got a bit confused there. By the way, how did you figure out this part - from psycopg2.errors import NotNullViolation - from the django docs?

Comment: @jarjarbinks99: no, if you look at the exception it mentions the type of the exception at the first line, so that is the one that should be imported.